# How to succesfully use CLIPSNet

Tags: c#, clips

I am trying to integrate CLIPS with C#,I have tried adding a reference to CLIPSNet.dll in my project.But when I copy the CLIPSLib.dll to the bin folder and try to bulid the solution I get this error message,

Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'CLIPSLib' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)
at CLIPSNet.Environment.CreateEnvironment(Int32 env)
at CLIPSNet.Environment..ctor()
at herbicide.Program.Main(String[] args) in  ..\repos\herbicide\Program.cs:line 9

How do I fix this so as to successfully run CLIPS from c#

Comment: You code send your code so we can help you to improve it.

Comment: using System;

namespace herbicide
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CLIPSNet.Environment theEnv = new CLIPSNet.Environment();
            theEnv.Load(@"Herbicide.clp");
            theEnv.Reset();
            theEnv.Run(-1);

        }
    }
}

Comment: Dear melo am a question reviewer it would be nice to open a new question with code included. so people will see all together and answer your question.